# How to create alpha numeric sequences in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I need to create alpha numeric sequence 
Example : I have 2 tables say city and student.
    I want sequence for city to be like "city1,city2,city3...." and for student like "stud1,stud2,stud3" etc

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more information by editing your question. What exactly have you tried? Why isn't that working? What does the table look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [`sequence`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) cannot be alphanumeric. In fact, you can't even restrict to a lesser numeric type in PostgreSQL: it's always a `bigint`.

But `sequence` is just one part of creating a column, which is like a so-called auto-increment.

PostgreSQL's pseudo type `serial` works like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

To achieve what you want, you only need to define custom `DEFAULT` expression, like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE city_city_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE city (
    city_id text NOT NULL DEFAULT ('city' || nextval('city_city_id_seq'))
);
ALTER SEQUENCE city_city_id_seq OWNED BY city.city_id;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `BEFORE INSERT` trigger for that. This trigger can get a number from a sequence and add a word to it.

Other option is to use a simple `VIEW` on top of the table.

UPD: Using a custom default like  `DEFAULT ('city' || nextval('city_city_id_seq'))` (from pozs answer) is better than using a trigger.